# Breaking it gently

Tags: hash, attack-prevention

Let's say I've found a fundamental error with mathematics of a security package. For example, let's say I've found something similar to the Pollard’s \rho-1 algorithm that renders some of the RSA keys vulnerable.

If I am a benevolent person, what is the best way to publish this result without wreaking havoc?

I am not certain if this question can be answered; but any pointers to minimizing the damage will be appreciate; not publishing the result is not an option.

Comment: I would inform the owner of the package first. Only if the ower does not respond in a timely manner a full disclosure would be appropriate.

Comment: This is a topic of active debate: [Full_Disclosure_Topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_disclosure_(computer_security)). An important factor in your decision making will be the importance of the mentioned security package. For smaller things, I would agree with @UwePlonus.

Comment: Don't go full disclosure.  Report it to CERT or Mitre,  and let them handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the Responsible Disclosures method

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsible_disclosure

in which a vulnerability is disclosed only after a period of time that allows for the vulnerability or issue to be patched

So contact the maintainer of the package first , and allow them time to fix it before publishing your findings